# How can I make user creation public but read access private in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I'd like to make user creation public, so that unauthenticated users can create new accounts in `_users`, but only give read privileges to `admin` roles. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CouchDB 1.1.0 and the upcoming 1.1.1 do not support this. The best you can do is to have a public database where users submit requests to create user accounts, and you have a standalone tool to react to that and create normal user accounts. (The standalone tool could simply be a dedicated web page you log in to as the admin.)

I have submitted a patch to do exactly what you describe. Called the [CouchDB inbox database](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1287), it allows unprivileged users to write some approved documents to the database, but they cannot read any of the data. Creating new user accounts is exactly why I made the patch.

I am optimistic that it will be included in either v1.2 or 1.3.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just might apply that patch myself. I already am applying the update_handler 'any-http-code returned' patch anyway.